# Find the bugs related to test a run in Quality Center via database query

Tags: quality-center, sql

I'm able to query a HPQC database to retrieve execution information from the TEST and STEP tables.

I'm also able to query for defect information from the BUG tab.

But, I'm struggling to find a way to fetch the list of defects that have been associated with a failing step/test - could someone provide me a query that can join tests to bugs, or point me to the table that contains this information?

This is on an old HPQC 9.2 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was easily done using the LINKS table - here's an example of query to retrieve all the RUNS a bug is associated with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LN_BUG_ID as BugId, LN_ENTITY_ID AS EntityId
FROM td.LINK
WHERE LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'RUN'
UNION
SELECT LN_BUG_ID, ST_RUN_ID
FROM td.LINK
INNER JOIN td.STEP
ON LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID = STEP.ST_ID
WHERE LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'STEP'
UNION
SELECT LN_BUG_ID, RN_RUN_ID
FROM td.LINK
INNER JOIN td.RUN
ON LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID = RUN.RN_TESTCYCL_ID
WHERE LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TESTCYCL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below link has the query and information to link the test lab and defects. [how-to-retrieve-requirement-test-case](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/how-to-retrieve-requirement-test-case.html)

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Sham. On stackexchange links are usually not enough. It would help others if you summarize the content of the link.